# Where is the leak here?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I don't understand where is the leak here.

I am querying for a field in the database. After this, I am inserting in a NSMutableArray list.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bList;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *icon;//Model

Model *newModel = [[Model alloc] init]; 
newModel.icon = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
[self.bList addObject:newModel];
[newModel release];
```

And in the end:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.bList release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Nope, not yet. I lost half a day by now to find something....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    [self.bList release];
```

Don't do that;  either use `self.bList = nil;` or `[bList release], bList = nil;`

There doesn't appear to be a leak in that code, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Remember that `leaks` identifies where the leak was allocated, not where it was leaked.  The leak is likely caused by an over-retain elsewhere.

Comment: Why not [self.bList release];?

Comment: Because you'll end up w/a dangling pointer.   It really doesn't matter in this case, but it is a style thing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment on `@murat`'s answer, If you are doing,

```
self.blist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

then you are leaking memory as you are taking ownership twice in that line. One by `alloc-init` and one based on the property (assuming it is `retain`ed, mostly should be). In such case releasing it once in `dealloc` won't balance the `retain-release` calls. You will have to rather do,

```
self.blist = [NSMutableArray array];
```

or

```
self.blist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
```

Comment: In which case, you are releasing `blist` more than necessary. Here you are taking ownership only once and relinquishing it only in the `dealloc`. That should balance the memory management calls. If this move is a problem then you've to remove additional release calls on `blist`.

Answer (score -2):

You create an instance of array but did not take a memory space for it. For your blist array, allocate a memory space.

```
self.blist= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // or you can create like
self.blist= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:100];
```

Comment: but do this before addobject part

Comment: so then i do not see any memory leak. maybe do not do [self.blist release] do it without release [blist release]

Comment: The array will expand as needed.  `allocWithCapacity:` is never required.